# How to get only the values from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
product_list = ['apple', 'orange']
price_list = {0:'100', 1:'110'}


price_product_list = {}
print(products_list)
for k in products_list:
    for l in price_dict.items():
        price_product_list[k] = price_dict
print(price_product_list)
```

output:

```
{'apple': {0:'100', 1:'110'}, 'orange':{0:'100', 1:'110'}
```

But how to add only the price values to the respected products

Expected output

```
{'apple':100, 'orange':110}
```

Comment: Please just use a research engine before post on SO. This is a basic thing that you can find everywhere on the web ex : https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/values

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension that does indexing, like this:

```
product_list = ['apple', 'orange']
price_list = {0:'100', 1:'110'}
print({product_list[k]:v for k,v in price_list.items()})
```

Result:

```
{'apple': '100', 'orange': '110'}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `price_dict.values()` instead of `price_dict.items()`.

The `values()` method of dict allows you to iterate through the values of your dictionary, while `items()` returns a tuple (key, value).

For more information on the dictionary methods : https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict